# UPDATE sql query when button pressed?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

So what I want to do is run an UPDATE query to my sqlite database when I press a button. Below is what I have and its not working, what I think is the problem is that I'm opening the database from the bundle, which of course is read only. Now I've been doing some research and I realized that I should:

1. Check for the existence of the database in the Documents folder.
2. If not there, copy the database from the bundle to the Documents folder.
3. Now, open the database from the Documents folder.

But I'm don't know how to do that??? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have:

```
- (IBAction)update:(id)sender {
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath  ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }
    const char *sql = "UPDATE strengthexercises SET isFavorite = 'true' WHERE ID = '1'";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

}
```

A clear answer with an example would help a lot. Thanks in advance.

**Update #1**

Now I have this, but it still dose not work...

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
return basePath;
}

 - (IBAction)update:(id)sender {
@try {
    NSString *docsPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if (!fileExists) {
        // get the source path to copy from
        NSString *dbSourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath  ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
        // copy db to documents
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbSourcePath toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    const char *sql = "UPDATE strengthexercises SET isFavorite = 'true' WHERE ID = '1'";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to return the documents path like this -

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {   
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
     return basePath;
}
```

then check if db exists at documents path -

```
NSString *docsPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSString *dbDocsPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises-1.sqlite"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbDocsPath];
```

use conditional to determine if db needs copying and if so copy -

```
if (!fileExists) {
     // get the source path to copy from
     NSString *dbSourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StayhealthyExercises-1" ofType:@"sqlite"];
     // copy db to documents
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbSourcePath toPath:dbDocsPath error:nil];
}
```

You should now have a copy of your db in the documents that you can read/write to.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have but it still doesn't work, any clues?

Comment: i narrowed the problem down, with that code it cant even read it...anysuggesstions

Comment: it says that dbSourcePath is an undeclared identifier, im guessing because its in the if statement

Comment: are you able to confirm the copying of the db, by navigating to documents directory for simulator or use organiser to explore device

Comment: ok so may I suggest doing some cave man logging. Start with logging dbSourcePath. I'm curious if pathForResource:ofType: should be used instead of resourcePath method of NSBundle.

Comment: i don't even get into the if(!fileExists) {} statement so I can't log it. so the issue is before then